# Bluetooth does not work with my acer aspire v5 573g

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth, acer

I just have installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Acer Aspire v5 573g. The bluetooth was working fine with my speaker during one day but it stopped suddenly. The speaker is working with another device so it is clearly my laptop that do not handle bluetooth anymore.

I have installed `blueman` which can detect my speaker but cannot connect it. I have tried:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all

sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

It does not help.

The result of `sudo rfkill list` is:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

3: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have no idea what to do next. Any suggestion?

Edit: i have set Enable=Socket in /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf and now the device connect! But it is not recognized by PulseAudio, so i cannot redirect sound to the speaker.

Here is the syslog when the speaker connects:

```
Feb 16 20:21:08 mamachine pulseaudio[5121]: [pulseaudio] module-bluetooth-device.c: 00:0C:8A:A3:5E:34 is not known.
```

`Feb 16 20:21:08 mamachine pulseaudio[5121]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-bluetooth-device" (argument: "address=00:0C:8A:A3:5E:34 profile=a2dp"): initialization failed.`
How can i make my device recognized PulseAudio? Upgrade bluez? (I dont know how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Problem with my V5-573g

First thing to do is:

```
sudo lsusb
```

If you do not see your bluetooth device listed check if it is just turned off with an hotkey. (Example FN + F6)

If you have the same Model you shoud see this:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3f6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0489:e04e Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

If not a Bios Update helped me

http://www.acer.de/ac/de/DE/content/drivers